# MongoDB Error Import CSV file in Database

Tags: mongodb

> When Import this CSV file in mongoDB we get error message given below

```
mongoimport --db betahrprocesses --collection cityStates --type csv --headerline --file /Applications/MAMP/pincode.csv
```

> Error Message ::

```
2017-02-23T11:54:32.911+0530 E QUERY    [main] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running it in OS shell, not mongo shell:

```
vao@vao-VirtualBox:~$ mongo --quiet
> mongoimport --db betahrprocesses --collection cityStates --type csv --headerline --file pincode.csv
2017-02-23T09:02:16.954+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:14
```

Now exit mongo shell and run in os shell:

```
> ^C
vao@vao-VirtualBox:~$ mongoimport --db betahrprocesses --collection cityStates --type csv --headerline --file pincode.csv
2017-02-23T09:02:27.079+0000    connected to: localhost
2017-02-23T09:02:27.080+0000    imported 1 document
```

Check the result:

```
vao@vao-VirtualBox:~$ mongo --quiet
> use betahrprocesses
switched to db betahrprocesses
> db.cityStates.find().limit(1);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58aea41d6734f211a86e2346"), "int" : 0, "string" : "one" }
```

Comment: tiladminsmbp46:bin chandan.k$ ./mongoimport --db betahrprocesses --collection city --type csv --headerline --ignoreBlanks --file /Applications/MAMP/pincode.csv
2017-02-23T14:43:42.135+0530 connected to: localhost
2017-02-23T14:43:42.135+0530 imported 0 documents

Comment: It cannot import CSV file imported 0 document

Comment: I assume it is completely different error then?.. And has nothing to do with your question?

Comment: First one is resolved but i cannot import CSV file it display imported 0 document, i think CSV file format error, what is the exact file column format for import CSV in mongodb, can you please send me your imported csv file

Comment: If your question is resolved, mark it resolved. If you have more questions, ask more questions. SO is not support service. It is meant to have typical solutions to typical problems given and saved

Comment: hey, i m not going to mark it resolved, without final solution. please provide me the same then i will mark resolve